# crear diseño tabla html

Tags: html, css3

Alguien me puede ayudar o indicar como  crear esta tabla en `html`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes el Html hecho? Si proporcionas el html, sera mas rapido para nosotros ayudarte con el css

Comment: Hola Eduard, recuerda que siempre que hagas una pregunta debes saber [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Es importante que ya tengas por lo menos cierta parte del código ya hecho! aquí te dejo, [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu table de la imagen puedes hacerla en html asi:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="3">Store Location</th>
    <th rowspan="3">Gender</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3">2013</th>
    <th colspan="3">2014</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Q1</th>
    <th>Q2</th>
    <th>Q3</th>
    <th>Q1</th>
    <th>Q2</th>
    <th>Q3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Boston</th>
    <th>Male</th>
    <td>17713</td>
    <td>17713</td>
    <td>17713</td>
    <td>17713</td>
    <td>17713</td>
    <td>17713</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Female</th>
    <td>43761</td>
    <td>43761</td>
    <td>43761</td>
    <td>43761</td>
    <td>43761</td>
    <td>43761</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Los Angeles</th>
    <th>Male</th>
    <td>17713</td>
    <td>17713</td>
    <td>17713</td>
    <td>17713</td>
    <td>17713</td>
    <td>17713</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Female</th>
    <td>43761</td>
    <td>43761</td>
    <td>43761</td>
    <td>43761</td>
    <td>43761</td>
    <td>43761</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">New York</th>
    <th>Male</th>
    <td>17713</td>
    <td>17713</td>
    <td>17713</td>
    <td>17713</td>
    <td>17713</td>
    <td>17713</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Female</th>
    <td>43761</td>
    <td>43761</td>
    <td>43761</td>
    <td>43761</td>
    <td>43761</td>
    <td>43761</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

esta bien para eso debes en tus header usar rowspan en las primeras columnas eso unira las celdas y luego colspan para unir las columnas en los años
aqui te dejo el codigo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <table border="1">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">location store</td>
    <td rowspan="2">gender</td>
    <td colspan="3">2013</td><td colspan="3">2014</td><td colspan="3">2015</td></tr>

   <tr>
    <td>q1</td><td>q2</td><td>q3</td>
    <td>q1</td><td>q2</td><td>q3</td>
    <td>q1</td><td>q2</td><td>q3</td>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <td>valor</td>
   <td>valor</td>
   <td>valor</td>
   <td>valor</td>
   <td>valor</td>
   <td>valor</td>
   <td>valor</td>
   <td>valor</td>
   <td>valor</td>
   <td>valor</td>
   <td>valor</td>
  </tbody>
 </table>

</body>
</html>
```